# Python - Determine if an exception was raised in a function

Tags: python, exception, except

I'm currently writing an extension to another Python library that I have no control over. The library has functions like this:

```
def xyz():
    try:
        sources = []
        ...
        #code that may add values to sources and may also throw an exception
        ...
        return sources
    except:
        return sources
```

If an empty list is returned, I want to somehow figure out if that is the case because an exception was thrown (before values could be added to sources), or because simply no values were added to sources (without throwing an exception).

Any ideas? Again, I don't have control over the function, so I can't change the return value or add the try->except outside the function.

Comment: Couldn't you edit the function where `except: return 1`

Comment: There are actually thousands of these functions. So there is no way I can change anything in the functions. And every time the developer of the external library releases an update I would have to check all the thousands of functions again, so no.

Comment: what if you monkeypatched the exceptions.BaseException instead and added an instance counter of sorts?  So that when __init__ gets called on it, it increments?  If you are not running multithreaded code, then you could check `Exception.counter == counter_before_call` after each call. smelly hack, for sure.  And, beware, Exceptions seem to use *\__slots\__*, making it that much harder.

Comment: Thanks JL, that is an idea that might just work.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to monkeypatch the lib's function with a sane implementation instead:

```
import insanelib

def myxyz():
    sources = []
    ...
    #code that may add values to sources and may also throw an exception
    ...
    return sources


insanelib.xyz = myxyz
```

Or you can submit a patch to the lib's author so he at least provide an option to *not* ignore exceptions.